# can i automatic onchange?

Tags: javascript

I have an input `A` that has an `onChange()` function that will change the value of label `B`. Can I make it so that I can change input `A` with inpurt `C` but input `A` will change the value inside input `B`?

```
<input name="addqty" id="C" onchange="addqty(this.id)">
<input name="qty" id="A" onchange="cal(this.id,value)">
<input name="qty" id="A2" onchange="cal(this.id,value)">
<label name="total" id="B"></label>
```

The input `A` is a quantity, `B` is the total price, and `C` is an additional quantity. I need to change the input `C` so that it will change the value of the inputs `A`, `A2`, etc. but will not change the value of `B`.
How can i fix the problem? Ps: there are many A field call from data base

Comment: Change the a from the b to the c but not the A2... Can you perhaps try to word the question so its less confusing.

Comment: So funny question. You made me cannot stop laughing =))

Comment: Also, please include the functions `cal` and `addqty` in your question as this will no doubt help with understanding your question.

Comment: It appears that you have two inputs with the same name, which won't let you sumbit both inputs.

Comment: @Shedokan actually it's quite possible

Comment: Yeah, your'e right sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand you correctly is the B TOTAL sum of all inputs? If so, modify your onchange  handler on C to calculate B label from all C and As inputs.

Or assign the same handler to all inputs and then by caller (id,name or object itself) take corresponding action. Or,but its quite  odd, set some global flag/variable in *cal* function which will prevent label udate in *addqty* and then reset it.

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag to true in the beginning of addqty, and set if to false at the end, and test the value of that flag in cal before you update B